# I get different outputs when running docker command with and without sudo

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I have this situation where I am trying to understand how I am able to get different outcomes for my running docker containers depending on whether I use `sudo` or not to list the running containers:

```
docker container list
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS              NAMES
b791664cefa9   groupkash-gunicorn-flask:v1.0   "/entrypoint.sh guni_"   3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes   80/tcp, 5000/tcp   groupkash-flask
```

Then with `sudo`:

```
sudo docker container list                                                                     CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS       PORTS                                                                      NAMES
49b16a3c22f0   groupkash-webserver:v1.0   "/docker-entrypoint._"   10 months ago   Up 2 hours   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, :::443->443/tcp   groupkash-webserver
78ed50d29da7   166d1283cf6a               "/entrypoint.sh guni_"   10 months ago   Up 2 hours   80/tcp, 5000/tcp                                                           groupkash-flask
```

The `flask` containers in both instances are the same based on their names but the `container id` are different. Note that I am these containers are created using using `docker compose` and I have a `frontend nginx container` and a `backend flask container`.

Comment: Are you on a native-Linux system, but with both Docker Desktop and the native Docker engine running?  Do you have an environment variable like `$DOCKER_HOST` set, or are you using the Docker CLI "context" feature in some way?

Comment: Yes, I have both desktop and native docker engine running. For context, I am using it on my Ubuntu system